# how to fix window.open("").closed returns true when opening the link of google search

Tags: javascript

```js
//if this is the link, return false
var tab = window.open("https://www.google.com.vn/", "_blank");

// if this is the link, reture true
// var tab = window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=coin&oq=coin&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i131i433i512j0i433i512l2j46i131i199i433i465i512j0i131i433i512j46i131i199i433i465i512j0i131i433i512j0i433i512j0i512.665j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8", "_blank");
// I want to know why it is true and how to fix it


setInterval(function() {
  checkTabsClosed()
}, 3000);

function checkTabsClosed() {
  console.log(tab);
  if (tab && tab.closed) {
    console.log("close");
  } else
    console.log("open");
}
```

Comment: It's not returning true, it's returning a WindowProxy object, per [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#return_value).  This is truthy: if(tab).. will be true.  There isn't any way to 'fix' this, I think: what behavior do you want here?

Comment: i want google search link to return false when i check tab.closed

Comment: i don't know why it returns true, the rest of the links are false, also fb, it also returns true, while that tab i haven't closed them yet

Comment: I was  unable to reproduce the problem in either Edge or Firefox using the code block in the post. Please update the post to create a code snippet that readers can run to reproduce the problem. If you need it,  help for formatting posts is available at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: In contrast, I can reproduce the problem in both Edge and Chrome.  The issue isn't that tab is false, it's that the WindowProxy object has .closed set to true even if the tab is still showing. This doesn't happen if you use the results of a Bing search. It's something to do with the Google search URL.